# Let $f(x,y)$ be polynomial, and $W = \left\{ {(x,y) \in R,f(x,y) = 0} \right\}$. Why does $W^o = \emptyset$??

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be polynomial, and $W = \left\{ {(x,y) \in R,f(x,y) = 0} \right\}$.

Why does $W^o = \emptyset$??

Comment: What does $A$ have to do with any of the previously-defined quantities?

Comment: @abiessu - I'm sorry.. bad typing.

Comment: I presume you mean $f$ and $F$ to be the same. You also need $f(x,y)$ not to be the zero polynomial. Also, what do you mean by $(x,y)\in R$? Do you mean $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another hint: If the interior were non-empty, it would contain some open ball, in which case for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ the one-variable polynomial equation $f(x_0, y)=0$ would have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: That's not a hint. That's a solution.

Comment: @DamianReding - Thanks, Why does equation $f(x_0, y)=0$, would have infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Well, if $W$ contains an open set, then in particular it contains a vertical line segment at $x=x_0$. And by definition of $W$ any point $(x_0, y)$ on this segment is a solution of  $f(x, y)=0$.

Comment: @DamianReding - Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: If you fix $y=y_0$, how many roots can the polynomial $p(x)=f(x,y_0)$ have? And what is the definition of an interior point?